# Single wordpress multi website down need help factoring what it is

Tags: php, multisite

A single website has gone down in our WordPress website multi-site. All the other sites work even using the same theme.

Solutions attempted Plugins removed Theme changed and removed. https://www.hilliardschools.org/hzn

Plugins removed Theme changed and removed. Upgraded PHP to 8.2

Comment: As noted in the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77809082/231316) that this was migrated from, you'll went to enable debugging to determine the specific problem.

Comment: Also, did you upgrade to PHP 8.2 as part of your troubleshooting, or is that what you think might have caused the issue?

Comment: We recently did. Thanks for helping me out on this. Discovered the issue was a code error in the functions file of the theme we were using.